# How to add automatically add a formula to a cell of a newly inserted row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

## The problem

We use a Google stylesheet in order to track the hours used on projects.

The process of creating a new project is:

01 Insert a new row

02  Copy-paste the formula that sums project hours, from a any previous project, to a cell of the newly inserted project-row.

[image]

- Link to demo-sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1amr7DExzp_nXPrEiaWV4EfJbbutv-TwkxKaC4HgM1VY/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to automate step 02, so that when one adds a new row, the formula is automagically added to the correct cell of the newly created project-row.

**How to add automatically add a formula to a cell of a newly inserted row?**

## Fill cell of active range on "Insert Row"

First I created a trigger that fires myFunction() "On change":

```
// run this only once to create a trigger (if necessary)
function initializeTrigger(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onChange()
   .create();
}
```

On change, myFunction() checks if the change-type is "INSERT_ROW", and if so, calls     setFormulaOnCellInActiveRange() and ouputs a message:

```
function myFunction(e){
  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW'){
    setFormulaOnCellInActiveRange();
    Browser.msgBox('Formula automatically added!');
  }
}
```

The setFormulaOnCellInActiveRange() function targets the active range,  because immediately after adding a row, the newly created row is highlighted as the active range:

```
function setFormulaOnCellInActiveRange() {

  // Get the active range
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getActiveRange();

  // Get the cell we want to target
  cell = activeRange.getCell(1,8);

  // Get the row index to be used in the formula
  cellRowIndex = cell.getRow();

  // Set the formula on the cell
  cell.setFormula(`=SUM(J${cellRowIndex}:${cellRowIndex})`);
  
}
```

Now, myFunction() and setFormulaOnCellInActiveRange() work just fine when they are apart but not when myFunction is tasked with calling setFormulaOnCellInActiveRange() on the "INSERT_ROW" change-type.

## Questions

First and foremost, is there a better way to solve the problem?

Second, do you might have any idea as to why it does not work to call setFormulaOnCellInActiveRange() on the insert-row change-type?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to go with BYROW and use a little workaround:

```
=BYROW(J9:25, LAMBDA(each, IF(COUNTA(each),SUM(each),"")))
```

As you see I've extended the formula up to that small row 25, then the "work around" is to insert the new row over row 25, then the range of BYROW will always continue to expand. Important: place this formula in H9 and delete all the other in that column

### UPDATE

In your locale and the ranges of your sheet. Tested it in a duplicate of the sheet:

```
=BYROW(J8:24;LAMBDA(each;IF(COUNTA(each);SUM(each);"")))
```

[image]

Comment: PS: in your demo sheet it would be up to row 24

Comment: Wow that was much easier than expected! I had previously tried a no-code approach without any success, but I guess that's because I am newbie when it comes to google-sheet-formulas. Can´t thank you enough for the help! I have implemented it on a copy of my original sheet-data and it works perfectly! I wish you a great weekend :)

Comment: I'm glad it was useful!! ARRAYFORMULA and all the LAMBDA functions are of great help for this kind of purposes. Good luck!!